# How can i get my location google image?

Tags: google-image-search

I just saw a template http://livedemo00.template-help.com/wordpress_39638/contacts/ and i liked the way google maps is used here, the image iframe value is http://maps.google.com/mapsf=q&source=s_q&hl=en&geocode=&q=Brooklyn,+NY,+USA&aq=0&sll=37.0625,-95.677068&sspn=47.704107,79.013672&ie=UTF8&hq=&hnear=Brooklyn,+Kings,+New+York&ll=40.649974,-73.949919&spn=0.01628,0.028238&z=14&iwloc=A&output=embed.

How can i generate my own location's google maps image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/embed/start has a pretty easy to follow series of 4 steps.

Comment: this seems to be my answer still is shows me "The Google Maps API server rejected your request. The provided API key is expired."